# How to use before_action on Doorkeeper::TokenController

Tags: ruby-on-rails, oauth, doorkeeper

I'm having trouble with Doorkeeper::TokensController.
I want to execute some code before an Access Token is asked for (if it's created or not, I want to log it anyway) using a `before_action` (default route is `POST /oauth/token` / `Doorkeeper::TokensController#create`.

I followed the doc [here](https://github.com/doorkeeper-gem/doorkeeper/wiki/Customizing-routes#changing-controllers) by doing the following:

**config/routes.rb**

```
  use_doorkeeper do
    controllers tokens: 'oauth/access_tokens'
  end
```

**app/controllers/access_tokens_controller.rb**

```
class Oauth::AccessTokensController < Doorkeeper::TokensController
  before_action :log_auth, only: [:create]

  def log_auth
    puts "I want to log here"
  end
end
```

But when I do `POST /oauth/token`, I have the following error message:

> ActionController::RoutingError (undefined method 'before_action' for Oauth::AccessTokensController:Class):
>   app/controllers/oauth/access_tokens_controller.rb:2:in 'class:AccessTokensController'
>   app/controllers/oauth/access_tokens_controller.rb:1:in 'top (required)'

What am I doing wrong? Is there a way to trigger a `before_action` or equivalent on `Doorkeeper::TokensController`?

Answer (score 7):

I found the answer, posting it here just in case someone needs it:

**1 - Doorkeeper**
First of all, Doorkeeper is built on `ActionController::Metal` (see [here](https://github.com/doorkeeper-gem/doorkeeper/blob/master/app/controllers/doorkeeper/application_metal_controller.rb)). It means that it doesn't come with all the features that you can use in a "classical" controller inheriting from `ActionController::Base`

**2 - Adding features**
In order to add some features to my `AccessTokensController` I had to include `AbstractController::Callbacks` like this:

```
class Oauth::AccessTokensController < Doorkeeper::TokensController
  include AbstractController::Callbacks
  before_action :log_auth, only: [:create]

  def log_auth
    puts "I want to log here"
  end
end
```

(thanks to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18189580/5353193) answer)